# How to use system GPU in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I tried a lot of things before I could finally figure out this approach. There are a lot of videos and blogs asking to install the Cuda toolkit and cuDNN from the website. Checking the compatible version. But this is not required anymore all you have to do is the following

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu

pip install cuda

pip install cudnn
```

then use the following code to check if your GPU is active in the current notebook

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()

tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

I just want to confirm, if these steps are enough to enable GPU in jupyter notebook or am I missing something here?

Comment: 1. what is the model of your GPU? 2. have you installed the correct version of TensorFlow (some GPUs require a very specific version of TensorFlow, e.g. NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti only works with TensorFlow 2.3.1)? 3. have you installed CUDA toolkit and CUDA drivers? See [Installation Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) here. Always start with the official documentation first.

Comment: @Raptor I am using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, installed Cuda toolkit version 11.3.1 and cudnn version 8.2.1. I also referred to this link [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and I also got True for tf.test.is_built_with_cuda(). Should I check anything else?

Comment: You should first check with the output of the codes above. Does it list out your GPU?

Comment: Yes it does, does that mean my jupyter notebook already using it?

Comment: @ThirunaavukkarasuM yes :))

Comment: Sadly tensorflow-gpu does not exist anymore, so the question material has gotten obsolete. The official installation guide lists two possible ways that are both problematic for Jupyter. 1) Running it in a controlled conda environment works for your computer, but it won't work inside a notebook. 2) Installing tensorflow-cpu or TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin makes it possible for the GPU to be seen in the notebook, but it may still refuse to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the compatible versions of CUDA and cuDNN (relative to your GPU), Tensorflow should use that since you installed `tensorflow-gpu`. If you want to be sure, run a simple demo and check out the usage on the task manager.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out a way to be sure that I am using my GPU resource. I am also trying to understand the efficiency of my GPU in running my Deep learning model. Is the code I mentioned in the post enough to make sure if I am using my GPU?

Comment: If your GPU shows up when running tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') it should be used